# redirect to a action that expects value in other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller **StepOfIdea**,and this controller has a action like this :

```
 StepOfIdeaRepository objStepOfIdearepository=new StepOfIdeaRepository();
        public ActionResult Index(int ideaId)
        {
            return View(objStepOfIdearepository.FindBy(i=>i.IdeaId==ideaId));
        }
```

So i have another controller named **idea** and this controller has a view named **index**

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClass.Idea>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>لیست</h2>
    @if (User.IsInRole("User"))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("ایده جدید", "Create", new {step = 1})
        </p>
    }
<table>
    <tr>
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
             <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Name)
        </th>

        }
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdeaPersion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdeaEnglish)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdeaResult)
        </th>


        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
         @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
             <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Name) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Name)
            </td>

        }
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdeaPersion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdeaEnglish)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdeaResult)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.RenderAction("ویرایش","index", stepofidea, new { id=item.Id }) |


        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("ویرایش", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("نمایش", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

In this line

```
    @Html.RenderAction("ویرایش","index", ????, new { id=item.Id }) |
```

I want to redirect to **index** action of  **stepOfIdea** controller and pass a value .But the above line doesn't work .

Comment: The `@Html.RenderAction` method has an overload that takes `string actionname`, `string controllername`, `object routevalues` respectively. The first parameter is always the action name

Comment: This may be lost in translation. Do you want to Redirect them (as in the URL changes) or do you simply want to render that action's output into the page? or do you want it to be a link that they click (and then the URL changes)?

Comment: Or do you want an `ActionLink`?

Comment: I need to redirect to a specefic controller in view .just it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you confused some terms in translation to English, and what you are actually looking for is to create an `<a href="">Link</a>` that also passes a variable.

You can do this very simply, by:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ویرایش", "Index", "StepOfIdea", new { id = item.Id }, null)
```

This will create the HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com/StepOfIdea/Index/5">ویرایش</a>
```

Comment: I need to  redirect to action of a controller (Not current controller) in my view.as you can see my view expect **Idea** model not **StepOfIdea** ,so i need to redirect to an action in **stepOfidea** controller in  **Idea** view

Comment: @EA fixed to go to a different controller. the null is important, to select the correct overload.